# rails to_json not following scropes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

When I just the to_json method it seems to ignore all other options... any ideas how to fix this?

```
var places = <%=raw @location_for_map.limit(5).to_json(:only => [:name, :lat, :lng]) %>;
```

I'm trying to plug in points from json on a google map, but noticed the points never got smaller with any of my scopes. where, order, limit...

I could put a limit(5) and it would still return 1000 records regardless.

The controller looks something like this:

```
sort = case params[:sort]
       when "name" then session[:sort] = "name"
       when "min_price" then session[:sort] = "min"
       when "avg_price" then session[:sort] = "cache_price"
       when "rating" then session[:sort] = "cache_rating DESC NULLS LAST"
       end

@locations = Location.find(params[:id])       
@base = @locations.places.active

#@location_for_map = @locations.places.limit(5)

unless params[:tags].blank?
  @base = @base.tagged_with(params[:tags])
end

unless params[:price_high].blank?
  price_high = (params[:price_high].to_f * Currency.rate(params[:currency]))
  price_low = (params[:price_low].to_f * Currency.rate(params[:currency]))
  @base = @base.where("cache_price BETWEEN ? AND ?",price_low,price_high)
end

@base = @base.order(session[:sort])

#@location = @locations.places.active.paginate :page => params[:page]
@location = @base.paginate :page => params[:page]
@location_for_map = @base
```

Comment: have you override serializable_hash or to_json method ?

Comment: no... i haven't touched either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how `to_json` behaves on collections that haven't fully been enumerated yet. It's probably a bug that it ignores your applied scopes, but this might work better:

```
@location_for_map.limit(5).all.to_json(:only => [:name, :lat, :lng])
```

`@location_for_map.limit(5)` doesn't actually return an array; it returns an object that represents all the scopes applied so far, and only actually fetches the array of results when you start treating that object like an array.

Applying the `all` method forces Rails to fetch the results immediately, and `to_json` probably knows better how to work with the actually array than the placeholder object. (All my guess, but give it a go, regardless.) Might be worth seeing if there's a bug report yet, and, if not, filing one.

Comment: yeah, i tried all in the beginning as i've run into that trick before, but it didn't seem to make a difference. @location_for_map.size always returns correctly.

Comment: i figured out the problem. it was something unrelated in the way i was updating the results.